# How many ways can you place 2 oranges and 2 apples at least one is on a black square?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The following is an interview question:

A picnic table is covered with a 2 by 4 grid of squares. Two of the squares are black and the rest are white. How many ways can you place 2 apples and 2 oranges such that at least one item is on a black square? Assume that at most one item can be placed in each square, the apples are indistinguishable and oranges are indistinguishable.

My thought process:

Total number of ways of arranging 4 items on 8 squares = `(8*7*6*5)*2! = 3360`

Total number of ways of arranging 4 items on 6 white squares only = `(6*5*4*3)*2! = 720`

Number of ways such that at least one item is on a black square = `3360 - 720 = 2640`

Is this correct? Also how would one do this problem if the apples were indistinguishable but the oranges were not?

Comment: You should not be multiplying by $2!$.  Even without that factor you are considering the pieces of fruit distinguishable.  In the first line, the $8$ is the number of ways to place the first apple and the $7$ is the number of ways to place the second.  You are counting each way of placing them twice.

Comment: Instead of *2!, you should have /2!2!

Comment: There are $\binom{8}{4}$ of deciding places for the fruits. Then, there are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways of deciding which of the four places will hold (indistinguishable) apples, and finally $\binom{2}{2}$ ways of placing the remaining (indistinguishable) oranges. Thus, the number of permissible ways of arranging the fruits on the eight squares is $\binom{8}{4} \binom{4}{2} \binom{2}{2}$, which is equal to your answer if you replace $2!$ with $/2!2!$ as suggested above.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense!

Answer (score 4):

An arrangement is obtained by first placing the two oranges among the eight squares (this is the same as selecting two squares, without order since the oranges are indistinguishable, hence $\binom 82$ ways) and then the two apples among the remaining six squares ($\binom 62$ ways for the same reason).

An arrangement on white squares only is obtained by first placing the two oranges among the six white squares ($\binom 62$ ways) and then the two apples among the remaining four white squares ($\binom 42$ ways).

Thus the answer is $\binom 82 \binom 62 - \binom 62 \binom 42 = 330$.